# Flexible RAM Benchmarking Tool

Tags: ram, benchmark

I'm trying to prove that an application I developed is saturating the memory bandwidth. For pure bandwidth benchmarking I'm aware that there's [STREAM](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/stream/ref.html), but it only measures the maximum sequential burst bandwidth in terms of MB/s.

I can see the memory transfers/second while using [PCM](https://github.com/opcm/pcm), but I need an external application to push the RAM with small (bytes, not kilobytes) random reads and random writes, to prove that the bandwidth I see is the maximum possible for the system.

**Edit:** I've clarified the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've obtained the numbers that I need via [SysBench](https://github.com/akopytov/sysbench), which can do memory benchmarks with random access and with small blocks down to 1KiB in size.